# is job hunting in the UK harder than in the US

Tags: united-kingdom, usa, job-hunting

As a non-EU (non US either) person, is job hunting in maths/physics fields in the UK harder than in the US? The reasons I suspect: UK has a smaller market; UK has stricter interviews.

I'm not asking from visa's point of view. Rather, from screening's and interview's point of view.

Comment: Also note the visa system differences between the two countries. As far as I know the UK Tier 2 visa is slightly easier to obtain than a US H1B because although the market is smaller the cap on the visa numbers is actually higher in the UK. In any case you might want to rephrase the question to be a bit more specific - like which field

Comment: @ SztupY compared to uk's t2 visa, h1b is frustrating and nothing to rely on. no, i'm not asking from visa's point of view

Comment: yeah but how easy it is to get a job highly depends on whether you'll get a visa or not, because no visa means no job. Since for a non-EU/US citizen getting a visa is harder in the US the requirements at a job interview will also be similarly harder - if not of other reasons because they'll only be able to sponsor applicants for middle/senior roles. I can only comment on the situation in the UK but we did hire plenty of junior/mid level people from overseas (Software Engineering)